# spring boot @PreAuthorize hasAuthority and hasRole

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to use `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('READ'), hasRole('ADMIN')")` that throws parsing exception.

How can I use `hasAuthority` and `hasRole` with `@PreAuthorize` in Spring boot controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked as

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('READ') and hasRole('ADMIN')")
```